# Class without java.lang.Object as a superclass

Tags: java, oop, object, inheritance

We know that by default, every class inherits ultimately from the `java.lang.Object` class, which is why methods such as `toString` are readily available to every class. Therefore, a generic class is effectively as follows:

```
public class Foo extends java.lang.Object {

public Foo() {super(); }
}
```

However, is it at all possible to create a class which does NOT automatically inherit from the `Object` class, and thus, has no superclass? And if so, what would be the effect?

Comment: No and therefore nil. Your question embodies a contradiction in terms. Either every class inherits ultimately from `java.lang.Object` or it doesn't, and it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can't write class without having `java.lang.object` as superclass. Compiler will automatically extend the object class.Only the object class itself and interfaces are the ones which do not extend object class.

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not possible. From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html):

> Class Object is the root of the class hierarchy. **Every class has**
>   **Object as a superclass**. All objects, including arrays, implement the
>   methods of this class.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe that you can have a class that does not inherit `Object`. Quoting from [Object as a Superclass](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html)..

> The Object class, in the java.lang package, sits at the top of the
>   class hierarchy tree. Every class is a descendant, direct or indirect,
>   of the Object class. Every class you use or write inherits the
>   instance methods of Object. You need not use any of these methods,
>   but, if you choose to do so, you may need to override them with code
>   that is specific to your class.

In cases where the inheritance is not explicitly stated, it is implicitly stated. Now, inheritance will obviously not form a cycle. The `Object` class is the only one which inherits from nobody, it's the top of hierarchy.